# Which p-value thresholds for a two-sided 90% confidence interval?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval, p-value, ab-testing, significance

I'm running an A/B test, and I want to check for statistical significance with 90% confidence two-sided. I've calculated standard errors, z-scores and p-values.

I'm saying that I have significance when my p-value is lower than 0.1 and greater than 0.9. Am I right? I'm using this tool https://vwo.com/blog/ab-testing-significance-calculator-spreadsheet-in-excel/

I'm doubting whether it should be lower than 0.05 and greater than 0.95.

I think I'm mixing things up in my head. Because, I have the p-value, and I'm saying that my alpha is 0.1. I'm not calculating the alpha/2 and p-value/2, nor I need it. So, should I just check if the p-value is lower than 0.1 and that's all? Not even greater than 0.9?

Answer (score 0):

90% confidence interval means you have **10%** as the **Region of Rejection**, which is divided into 2 equal halves on both sides in the **tail area**.

You are correct! Just check if the p-value is less than 5% or 0.05 and is greater than 95% or 0.95 as this range represents the **Region of Rejection**

If the p-value lies in the above range, you can reject the Null Hypothesis.

Comment: I found the template I was using! Do you think it's OK? https://vwo.com/blog/ab-testing-significance-calculator-spreadsheet-in-excel/ Thanks for your answer anyway.